# Retrieving sub-fields from parsed JSON in snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having some difficulty getting the individual components of the address component

`with data as (select 
    PARSE_JSON('{  "data" : [ 
    [ "row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry", "00000000-0000-0000-01B7-0B8F94EE5292", 0, 1486063689, null, 1486063689, null, "{ }", "410", "21206", "Frankford", "2", "NORTHEASTERN", [ "{\"address\": \"4509 BELAIR ROAD\", \"city\": \"Baltimore\", \"state\": \"MD\", \"zip\": \"\"}", null, null, null, true ], null, null, null ]
}') as j
     )
     select f.value[1][0]::text
            from data d,
        lateral flatten(input=> d.j:data,recursive=>TRUE) f;`

`f.value[1][0]` has a field address

`{"address": "4509 BELAIR ROAD", "city": "Baltimore", "state": "MD", "zip": ""}`

but 
`f.value[1][0].address` returns null

How do I get the individual attributes of f.value[1] like address, city, etc?

Comment: How does the JSON appear in the source? I'm not clear why the double backslashes are there in the literal value being sent to parse_json. A double backslash is an escaped single backslash, so this is adding single backslashes before the double quotes. I don't think you need to escape the double quotes at all here.

Comment: That was not the source, just some test json. Here is the actual json: `{"data" : [ 
 [ "row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry", "00000000-0000-0000-01B7-0B8F94EE5292", 0, 1486063689, null, 1486063689, null, "{ }", "410", "21206", "Frankford", "2", "NORTHEASTERN", [ "{\"address\": \"4509 BELAIR ROAD\", \"city\": \"Baltimore\", \"state\": \"MD\", \"zip\": \"\"}", null, null, null, true ], null, null, null ]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is given you have three levels of nested data, you should not be using `recursive=>TRUE` as the objects are not the same, so you cannot make anything of value out of the data. You need to break the different layers apart manually.

```
with data as (
  select 
  PARSE_JSON('{ data: [ [ "row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry", "0B8F94EE5292", 0, 1486063689, null, 1486063689, null, "{ }", "410", "21206", "Frankford", "2", "NORTHEASTERN", [ "{\\"address\\": \\"4509 BELAIR ROAD\\", \\"city\\": \\"Baltimore\\", \\"state\\": \\"MD\\", \\"zip\\": \\"\\"}", null, null, null, true ], null, null, null ]]}') as j
), data_rows as (
    select f.value as r
    from data d,
    lateral flatten(input=> d.j:data) f
)
select dr.r[0] as v0
    ,dr.r[1] as v1
    ,dr.r[2] as v2
    ,dr.r[3] as v3
    ,f.value as addr_n
from data_rows dr,
    lateral flatten(input=> dr.r[13]) f;
```

so this get all the rows (of which your example has only one) the unpacks the values of interest (you will need to complete this part and give v0 - vN meaning) but there is an array or addresses

```
V0  V1  V2  V3  ADDR_N
"row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry"    "0B8F94EE5292"  0   1486063689  "{\"address\": \"4509 BELAIR ROAD\", \"city\": \"Baltimore\", \"state\": \"MD\", \"zip\": \"\"}"
"row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry"    "0B8F94EE5292"  0   1486063689  null
"row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry"    "0B8F94EE5292"  0   1486063689  null
"row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry"    "0B8F94EE5292"  0   1486063689  null
"row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry"    "0B8F94EE5292"  0   1486063689  true
```

now to decode the address as json `,parse_json(f.value) as addr_n` does that, so you can break it apart like:

```
with data as (
  select 
  PARSE_JSON('{ data: [ [ "row-ea6u~fkaa~32ry", "0B8F94EE5292", 0, 1486063689, null, 1486063689, null, "{ }", "410", "21206", "Frankford", "2", "NORTHEASTERN", [ "{\\"address\\": \\"4509 BELAIR ROAD\\", \\"city\\": \\"Baltimore\\", \\"state\\": \\"MD\\", \\"zip\\": \\"\\"}", null, null, null, true ], null, null, null ]]}') as j
), data_rows as (
    select f.value as r
    from data d,
    lateral flatten(input=> d.j:data) f
)
select dr.r[0] as v0
    ,dr.r[1] as v1
    ,dr.r[2] as v2
    ,dr.r[3] as v3
    ,parse_json(f.value) as addr_n
    ,addr_n:address::text as addr_address
    ,addr_n:city::text as addr_city
    ,addr_n:state::text as addr_state
    ,addr_n:zip::text as addr_zip  
from data_rows dr,
    lateral flatten(input=> dr.r[13]) f;
```

you can ether leave the `addr_n` dummy variable or swap it out by cut'n'pasting it like so:

```
    ,parse_json(f.value):address::text as addr_address
    ,parse_json(f.value):city::text as addr_city
    ,parse_json(f.value):state::text as addr_state
    ,parse_json(f.value):zip::text as addr_zip
```

Comment: Thank you - you have made it very clear, I'm studying this now and can see why it has to be done the way it is presented.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the article for step-by-step for achieving it:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Using-lateral-flatten-to-extract-data-from-JSON-internal-field

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I am able to get the internal fields, but not the discrete values:
`select 
   f.value::text as fval, f.key as fkey
  from snowpipe.public.snowtable, 
    lateral flatten( input => JSONTEXT:data[0][13], recursive=>true ) f;` returns
`{"address": "4509 BELAIR ROAD", "city": "Baltimore", "state": "MD", "zip": ""}`

I am not able to get the individual values for address, city, etc. and the key field is null